# Como posso obter a data e a hora atual em #R?

Tags: r, datetime, data, time

Estou criando um relatório de processos de uma rotina, um "logfile" simplificado, e gostaria armazenar a data a hora do momento do erro em uma variável.

Qual a função que apresenta como resultado a data e hora do momento no #R?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A função que faz isso é a `Sys.time()`. Ela retorna a data e hora, junto com a timezone.

```
> Sys.time()
[1] "2016-03-08 07:11:57 BRT"
```

Se você quiser apenas a data pode usar a função `Sys.Date()`.

```
> Sys.Date()
[1] "2016-03-08"
```